# Get .IPA-file without physical iPhone

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, continuous-deployment, provisioning-profile

I have a Xamarin forms application, targeting Android and iOS. I am trying to add iPhone development to our CI and deployment cycle.

I am using Teamcity (CI), Octopus (Deployment), and HockeyApp (Distribution).

**Environment:**

Visual Studio for Mac running on a rented remote Mac. Am memeber of apple developer program and have provisioning profile etc.

**What I want:**

I want my remote Mac build agent to produce an .IPA file, in order to distribute it to our testers via HockeyApp.

**Actions:**

I select automatic provisioning with my Apple ID and my team set (Am registered in Apple developer program).

**What happens:**

> **...**
>
> Syncing devices for "X" team...
>
> Processing iPad devices...
>
> Processing iPhone devices...
>
> Processing iPod devices...
>
> Processing Apple Watch devices...
>
> Creating new iOS Development provisioning profile for VS Wildcard
>   application...
>
> **Automatic Provisioning failed: There are no current IOS devices on**
>   **this team matching the provided device IDs.**

**How do I fix this?**

p.s.

1. Do I need a to register a physical iPhone on the provisioning profile in order to produce an IPA?
2. Is it enough that I register one, or does it have to be connected to the remote agent?
3. Do you suggest better ways to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, for a standard developer account (Ad-hoc) provisioning profile, you will need to get the device's UDID from the physical device. You cannot create an Ad-hoc provisioning profile without at least 1 device ID provisioned in it.
2. You will need to register the UDID of each device on which you want to run the IPA, if you are using a standard developer account.  (See answer 3 for alternatives)
3. If you sign up for an Enterprise developer account ($299/year), you can create and Enterprise In House Distribution profile, and use it to sign your app.  Enterprise distribution profiles do not have specific devices registered, so you can build / sign the IPA, and any device can install and run it.  The installer will need to go in and trust you as a developer before running the app, but at least you don't have to register every single device before you build.

Comment: Our company has an ios application and we want to distribute the application to different companies without putting the app in the App Store.  Some of our customers  have an Airwatch MDM and they want to distribute our application inside their company. My question is : Do our company need and enterprise account or do customers need it? If I have an enterprise account,sign with in-house distribution and sen the ipa to our customers, can they distribute the ipa via their MDM?

Comment: They should be able to distribute your enterprise distribution signed app.  And since they have MDM, they should be able to push the provisioning profile for the app so that their employees do not have to trust the profile. Alternatively, they can get their own enterprise account and re-sign the binary you send them, if they want to manage the profiles / certificates themselves.  Note that enterprise In House distribution profiles expire after 1 year.

Comment: So, if I have one enterprise account, all my customers can distribute the app via their own MDM right? I don't need to have one apple enterprise account for each customer?

Comment: Yes, that is correct,  You can use the same account for all customers.  Although I would recommend creating a different provisioning profile for each of the customers under that one enterprise account.

Answer (score 0):

The provisioning profile seems to be Apple's way of making sure that only the predefined set of devices can use the ipa (so one doesn't just start distributing for production outside the app store).

So, the physical devices are needed, their udid's need to be baked into the provisioning profile which is then used to sign them off.